# Access BizTalk Orchestration Instances from database

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

Can I access persisted data of running orchestration Instances from the BizTalk database?

My BizTalk application deals with long-running processes and hundreds of orchestration instances can be running at a time.
I would like to access data persisted by these orchestration instances and display it on my application's UI. The data would give an insight about how many instances are running and at which state each of them is.

**EDIT :**
Let me try to be a little more specific.
My BizTalk application gets ticket requests (messages) from a source and after checking some business rules they are to be assigned to different departments of the company. The tickets can hop between inbox of different departments as each department completes its processing. 
Now, the BizTalk orchestration instances are maintaining all the information that which department owns a particular ticket at a given time. I would want to read this orchestration information and generate inbox for each of the department at runtime. I can definitely do this by pushing this information to a separate database and populate the UI from there BUT as all this useful information is already available in the form of orchestration instances I would like to utilize it and avoid any syncing issues.
Does it make any sense?

Comment: Are you looking for number of instances running or dehydrated?

Comment: In theory: yes it is possible and doable.
Is it practical? No.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your specific question is NO.

BAM exists *for this purpose exactly*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is doable. Your question is little confusing. You can't get the data which is persisted for your orchestration instance, however You can get number of running or dehydrated instances using various options like WMI, ExplorerOM library. As a starting point you can look at some samples provided as part of BizTalk installation under SDK\Samples\Admin folder. Also you should be looking at MSBTS_ServiceInstance WMI class to get the service instances. You can also look at a sample http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561219.aspx here. You can also use powershell to perform the same operation